# Neo4j Lucene query syntax for multi-word autosuggest fuzzy fulltext search

Tags: neo4j, lucene, full-text-search, fuzzy-search, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to implement Lucene query for multi-word autosuggest full-text search.

For example, I'd like to be able to search for `Arnold Schwarzenegger` in database.

Right now I can do the fuzzy search by one word:

```
Name.primaryName:Shwarzengger~
```

which returns:

```
Arnold Schwarzenegger
Katherine Schwarzenegger
Patrick Schwarzenegger
Christian Schwarzenegger
Aurelia Schwarzenegger
Patrick M. Knapp Schwarzenegger
Brian Schwarzenegger
Christina Schwarzenegger
```

but how to do the same for a multi-word term?

For example the following query:

```
Name.primaryName:arn Shwarzengger~
```

doesn't work with the following error:

> Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke
>   procedure `apoc.index.nodes`: Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: field must not be null

How to properly construct multi-word search term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Luchene language to search:

> CALL apoc.index.nodes('Company','name:Ne* AND employees:Ma*')
>
> https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_add_document_to_index

For example, break the initial query and construct a fuzzy one:

```
WITH "arnold schwarzenegger" AS queryString
WITH split(queryString, " ") AS terms,
     "primaryName" AS key
WITH REDUCE(
       acc = "", 
       i IN range(0, size(terms) - 2) | 
       acc + key + ":" + terms[i] + " OR "
     ) + key + ":" + terms[size(terms) - 1] 
     AS query
CALL apoc.index.nodes('Node', query) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! The query works like a charm!